# How to check ip blacklist using curl/wget request to mxtoolbox?

Tags: linux, curl, wget

I would like to add cron job to check server ip on blacklist.

something like

```
curl  'http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3a142.11.193.83' | grep 'you are on a blacklist.'
wget 'http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3a142.11.193.83' -Oq-  | grep 'you are on a blacklist.'
```

But it only download page without waiting mxtoolsbox checks.

What curl/wget request will be correct in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be better off doing the DNS requests to the blacklists directly yourself.

The overall bandwidth and time taken will be lower and you won't have to worry about parsing HTML and/or Javascript when you get the responses back.  Mxtoolbox are under no obligation to send the HTML or javascript back in the same format every time.

If you want to get fancy, you can run your own caching DNS resolver locally so that the DNS TTLs are automatically honoured and you din't cause unnecessary burden on the blacklist DNS servers.